# 'Map' object has no attribute 'on_displayed

Tags: python, leaflet, ipyleaflet

I get an error when I run the code below in jupiter lab. How can I fix ?

```
# Set study area using ipyleaflet
m = Map(center=(14, -90), zoom = 6)
draw_control = DrawControl(polyline={}, circlemarker={}, polygon={})
draw_control.rectangle = {
    "shapeOptions": {
        "fillColor": "#fca45d",
        "color": "#fca45d",
        "fillOpacity": 0.2
    }
}
m.add_control(draw_control)
m
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 2
      1 # Set study area using ipyleaflet
----> 2 m = Map(center=(14, -90), zoom = 6)
      3 draw_control = DrawControl(polyline={}, circlemarker={}, polygon={})
      4 draw_control.rectangle = {
      5     "shapeOptions": {
      6         "fillColor": "#fca45d",
   (...)
      9     }
     10 }

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipyleaflet/leaflet.py:457, in Map.__init__(self, **kwargs)
    455 def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    456     super(Map, self).__init__(**kwargs)
--> 457     self.on_displayed(self._fire_children_displayed)
    458     if self.default_tiles is not None:
    459         self.layers = (self.default_tiles,)

AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'on_displayed'
```

I get an error when I run the code below in jupiter lab. How can I fix ?

Comment: Try upgrading! `pip install ipyleaflet --upgrade`

Comment: pip install ipyleaflet --upgrade not working